How can I know which not installed RPM package contains a not installed command?
Suse Tumbleweed, I'd like to install tlmgr, I tried sudo zypper install -no-recommends texlive-tlmgr to no avail, I want to know which package contains the command tlmgr or equivalently the file /usr/bin/tlmgr.
How can I find the name of the uninstalled package that contains a command that I need?

"zypper's search command can check file lists when used with the -f option."

@muru I saw that discussion before posting but I was mislead  by the  reference to Debian in its title, I'll close my question asap!

Either of these should work:
zypper search --provides tlmgr
cnf tlmgr
dnf whatprovides tlmgr

